# Calculating totals by month based on two dates in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have a dataframe containing two columns of dates: `start date` and `end date`. I need to set up a dataframe where all months of the year are set up in separate columns based on the start and end date intervals so I can sum values from another column for each of the months per `name`.

To illustrate:

```
Original df:

Start Date   End Date   Name   Value
10/22/20     01/25/21   John   100
10/12/20     04/30/21   John   50
02/25/21     None       John   20


Desired df:
Name    Oct_20  Nov_20  Dec_20  Jan_21  Feb_21  Mar_21  Apr_21  May_21 Jun_21   Jul_21  Aug_21  ...
John    150     150     150     150     70      70      70      20      20      20      20      ...
```

Any suggestions or pointers on how I could achieve that result would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you show us your code plz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert values to datetimes with replace non datetimes to missing values and replace them to some `date`, then in list comprehension get all months to `Series`, which is used for pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
end = '2021-12-31'
df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'])
df['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'], errors='coerce').fillna(end)

s = pd.concat([pd.Series(r.Index,pd.date_range(r.Start, r.End, freq='M'))
                for r in df.itertuples()])

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': s.index}, s).join(df)

df2 = df1.pivot_table(index='Name',
                      columns='Date',
                      values='Value',
                      aggfunc='sum',
                      fill_value=0)

df2.columns = df2.columns.strftime('%b_%y')
print (df2)
Date  Oct_20  Nov_20  Dec_20  Jan_21  Feb_21  Mar_21  Apr_21  May_21  Jun_21  \
Name                                                                           
John     150     150     150      50      70      70      70      20      20   

Date  Jul_21  Aug_21  Sep_21  Oct_21  Nov_21  Dec_21  
Name                                                  
John      20      20      20      20      20      20
```

Comment: Thanks! In the actual dataset I have multiple start dates coinciding on the same "name". The suggestion here creates a separate column for each such instance. Let's say I have value valid from June to Jan, and then another one from November to Jan, it will create a separate column for each of the two aggregates, i.e. two November, two Dec, two Jan. Any clue how to aggregate all items valid for the same month regardless of different start dates?

Comment: @Zaphod - No idea, unfortunately.

Comment: If approaching this from a slightly different perspective, assuming we had all the months set up already in separate columns, would `df1.pivot_table` mentioned in your answer then be able to populate the relevant months with value sums corresponding to the month in question. Would that be possible?

Comment: @Zaphod - Is possible add some data to question with expected ouput for explain more problem with data?

Comment: I made another post building on this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67701488/pandas-sum-month-over-month-based-on-start-and-end-date-ranges)