# Pandas: Sum month-over-month based on start- and end date ranges

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Building on [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67398755/calculating-totals-by-month-based-on-two-dates-in-pandas), I have a dataframe like the following:

```
in_df:

Index    Name    Value    Start Date   End Date
0        John    100      21/05/2021   31/12/2021
1        John    50       01/01/2021   31/07/2021
2        John    20       20/02/2021   31/10/2021
3        Mary    40       15/01/2021   30/04/2021
4        Mary    30       20/03/2021   31/08/2021
5        Mary    20       20/03/2021   15/05/2021
```

I need to set up a dataframe which contains all months of the year and based on `in_df` aggregates and sums totals for each `name`, as here follows:

```
out_df:

Index    Name    Jan-21  Feb-21  Mar-21  Apr-21  May-21  June-21  Jul-21  Aug-21  Sep-21  Oct-21  Nov-21  Dec-21   
0        John    50      70      70      70      170     170      170     120     120     120     100     100
1        Mary    40      40      90      90      50      30       30      30      0       0        0       0
```

It's important that each month of the year is represented as columns only once with one sum value per `name`. The suggestion posted by @jezrael in the post referenced above will create a separate month column for each entry, leading to multiple `Mar-21`, for instance, in the example above where `Index 4` and `Index 5`both have a start date in March.

Any suggestions to have I might approach this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Follow the steps

1. Parse the strings in the `Start` and `End` date columns to datetime

```
end = pd.to_datetime(df['End Date'], dayfirst=True)
start = pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date'], dayfirst=True)
```

2. Generate the monthly **period range** corresponding to `Start` and `End` date column

```
df['period'] = [pd.period_range(*v, freq='M') for v in zip(start, end)]
```

3. `Explode` the dataframe on `period` and `pivot` the exploded dataframe with aggregation function `sum`

```
out = df.explode('period').pivot_table(
        'Value', 'Name', 'period', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
out.columns = out.columns.strftime('%b-%y')
```

#### Result

```
>>> out

period  Jan-21  Feb-21  Mar-21  Apr-21  May-21  Jun-21  Jul-21  Aug-21  Sep-21  Oct-21  Nov-21  Dec-21
Name                                                                                                  
John        50      70      70      70     170     170     170     120     120     120     100     100
Mary        40      40      90      90      50      30      30      30       0       0       0       0
```